# computing $L_2$ norm

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $x_i, i=1, \ldots, N$ are in $R$. Consider $\bar x=\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$. Let vector $y$ has component $x_i-\bar x, \quad i=1, \ldots, N$.

Compute the norm $\|y\|_2$.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: I just went by definition $\|y\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\bar x)^2=\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i)^2$ and here I am stuck. Not sure on how to move on. Should I open up brackets even further or it should be some kind of a "trick" here? Thank you.

Comment: Open the brackets of $\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x)^2$ up, and then sum things up and see some simplifications, noting that $N\bar{x} = x_1+x_2+...+x_N = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$.